Unable to Connect to Kubernetes Cluster via `kubectl` due to TLS Certificate Issue (x509: certificate signed by unknown authority)
I am trying to connect to my Kubernetes cluster (k3s) running on a Raspberry Pi using kubectl from my Windows machine. I have already verified that the token is valid, and I have retrieved the ca.crt file used by the cluster to configure the local machine. However, I am encountering the following error when running kubectl get nodes:
E1223 10:45:09.325814   14240 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://cluster.example.com/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Here’s the scenario:

K3s Cluster is running on a Raspberry Pi with IP 192.168.0.101.
API Server is exposed via Cloudflare at https://cluster.example.com.
The Windows machine is behind a corporate firewall and uses ca.crt (from the cluster) for authentication.
I've added the ca.crt file to the local machine and configured it in the kubeconfig file under the certificate-authority setting.

Things I've tried so far:

Verified that the certificate is valid and not expired.

Used the correct ca.crt file in the kubeconfig.

Tried connecting via curl:
curl --cacert ./ca.crt https://cluster.example.com

But I received the error:
curl: (60) schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT


Checked if the port 6443 is open, and the firewall settings on the Raspberry Pi allow connections.


ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
6443                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
32581/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5432                       ALLOW       192.168.0.105             
6443 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
32581/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Additional Information:

When I run telnet cluster.example.com 6443 from the Windows machine, I get:
Connecting To cluster.example.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 6443: Connect failed


I have access to the Raspberry Pi and the k3s server via SSH.

Error Messages:

kubectl throws the x509 certificate signed by unknown authority error.
curl throws the untrusted root certificate error.

Questions:

How can I resolve the certificate trust issue between my Windows machine and the k3s server?
How can I get the correct and full certificate chain to use in kubectl?
Is there an issue with Cloudflare's SSL settings, or do I need to update my certificates?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
The flow is depicted in the diagram below.

